# code in python that cannot be disrupted once it's started

Tags: python, runtime-error, atomic, fault

I have some Python code dealing with files. I think idearly that once those few lines of code have started, I'd like them to get to the end without disruption by unexpected errors or any other sorts of problems that could occur. Is there a way of notating this? Either generally for all code, or specifically for file IO.

```
print("clearing directory")
try: shutil.rmtree(path)
except OSError: print("error clearing " + path)
try: os.mkdir(path, 0o755)
except OSError: print("error recreating " + path)
```

Comment: I imagine that you're using multithreading to work concurrently, aren't you? What about using semaphores? https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects

Comment: Feel free to include that in your answer. :) But I'm afraid that in my case it's nothing so interesting. It's not problem, but I am curious.

Comment: rename before doing rmtree? that way the old name is not taken, and the rename operation is very fast

Comment: You might need to clarify what you mean by atomic here and what you're trying to protect against. Atomicity is normally used to prevent two threads reading/modifying a variable at the same time. "Unexpected errors" seems like an entirely different issue with a different solution.

Comment: Clarified @Kemp I hope this is a more general question than just the code I posted.

Comment: I think you might be using a much too broad definition of what atomic means here. Again, atomicity is a means to protect shared resources when multiple threads (or such) may access them at the same time. General error handling isn't the same thing. The idea of catching errors and continuing, which seems to be what you're really asking about, isn't related to atomicity. It's also what your code already does.

Comment: reworded to be about disruption rather than atomicity, if this is as good as it gets short of a comment that says "don't add code to the middle of this block of code", then that'd be a good answer